# How do I get a workspace containing all commits of a bitbucket (mercurial) repository?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, pydev, bitbucket

I've just started using Mercurial (hosted on bitbucket, interface is through eclipse pydev), and am very confused. My apologies for the very basic question, but I could not google an answer. I tried reading the mercurial tutorial, but to no avail.

So here goes:

I created a bitbucket and uploaded my code. When I do an "hg clone", I get a local workspace with a copy. That's good.

Now I've pushed some commits. I can see them in bitbucket. That's good too.

Now is the part which confuses me: 
When I do another "hg clone" to a different workspace, it does not get populated with the latest commits, but rather with the original set of files I uploaded.

How can I get a workspace populated with the latest set of commits?

My apologies for the newbie questions and for probably not using the right vernacular.

Thanks
Yaron

Comment: Did you push a new branch (different from the default one)? What `hg branch` returns?

Comment: Is it possible you did push your commits to a different branch at the upstream repo?

Comment: Here's an example of one of the commits:
Commit dd3989b52961 Raw commit »

commit
    dd3989b52961
parent
    81bc2c9c0ba9
branch
    default

added default for _temp

Who
    ...
When
    ...


So seems to me like I'm pushing to the default branch.

Comment: And what `hg parents` return on your second cloned repo? Would an `hg pull` improve the situation on that second clone? From http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TutorialClonen it really should checkout the tip of that `default` branch.

Comment: Is your bitbucket repo public? Helps if we could take a look.

Comment: @VonC: You mean http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TutorialClone

Comment: @LaurensHolst, yes the extra 'n' at the end of the TutorialClone url was a typo